# MySQL relationship based query runs below 1s but fails when I add a little more conditions/complexity (No error, InnoDB)

Tags: mysql, eloquent, lumen

I'm running a laravel/lumen app.
The SQL is auto generated using Eloquent so it might be a reason it's wonky.
It's querying qualifications table based on exists on groups and dictionaries tables which are in many-many relationship to it.

Following query fails - It hangs running infinitely... Clogs mysql. (Gives no error - empty mysql, php, apache logs).

https://codebeautify.org/sqlformatter/y22875bc2

However if i substract 1-2 random conditions, hence reducing complexity it runs perfectly beneath 1s.

To give some context I'm running a following api query.

```
http://localhost:8000/qualification
?with=dictionaries,groups1,groups2
&limit=20
&offset=0
&metadata=false
&status=funkcjonująca,|włączona
&category=!uregulowane
&groups1>name_pl=NAUKI ŚCISŁE I PRZYRODNICZE
&groups2>name_pl=Geografia,geologia,geofizyka
&hobby=przyroda
&expectation=kultura osobista,zainteresowanie modą,dobry węch
&edulvl=Branżowe,|Średnie,|Wyższe,|Inne pozaformalne
```

The DB runs on InnoDB. It has proper keys and indices.

I`d say it behaves like I'm running into some resources, memory cap? Am I wrong?

When I run an explain select on this I get the same behavior. Runs when a little simplier. Fails when full query is tested.

Comment: The problem is that without explain results it is pretty difficult to tell where thing go south. Also, as I understand the query is generated, so optimising the query itself may not help. I noticed that there is an `or` operator in the where clause, so you could try running 2 queries and use a union to satisfy all conditions. You should also share the relevant tables' structure, including the various indexes.

Comment: "It hangs running infinitely" - does it still show as "executing" in the processlist? How long have you waited before killing it? Please add the CREATE TABLE statements for qualifications, dictionaries, dictionary_qualification, groups, group_qualification to your question. The query and EXPLAIN output for an example query which completes and one which fails would be a good idea. Please include the query in a codeblock instead of linking out to a 3rd party.

Comment: Please share more details, like the query you are running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without having more detail it is impossible to tell where things are going wrong. There are some things which can be cleaned up. The following two groups of `or exists()` criteria can be condensed -

```
select * 
from `qualifications` 
where (
    exists (
      select * 
      from `dictionaries` 
        inner join `dictionary_qualification` on `dictionaries`.`id` = `dictionary_qualification`.`dictionary_id` 
      where 
        `qualifications`.`id` = `dictionary_qualification`.`qualification_id` 
        and `type` = ? 
        and `content_pl` = ?
    ) 
    or exists (
      select * 
      from `dictionaries` 
        inner join `dictionary_qualification` on `dictionaries`.`id` = `dictionary_qualification`.`dictionary_id` 
      where 
        `qualifications`.`id` = `dictionary_qualification`.`qualification_id` 
        and `type` = ? 
        and `content_pl` = ?
    )
)
```

can be reduced to -

```
select * 
from `qualifications` 
where (
    exists (
        select * 
        from `dictionaries` 
        inner join `dictionary_qualification` on `dictionaries`.`id` = `dictionary_qualification`.`dictionary_id` 
        where `qualifications`.`id` = `dictionary_qualification`.`qualification_id` 
        and (
            (`type` = ? and `content_pl` = ?) or
            (`type` = ? and `content_pl` = ?)
        )
        /* or if type is same for both
        and `type` = ?
        and `content_pl` IN (?, ?)
        */
    ) 
)
```

Similarly -

```
select * 
from `qualifications` 
where (
    exists (
      select * 
      from `dictionaries` 
        inner join `dictionary_qualification` on `dictionaries`.`id` = `dictionary_qualification`.`dictionary_id` 
      where 
        `qualifications`.`id` = `dictionary_qualification`.`qualification_id` 
        and `type` = ? 
        and `content_pl` = ?
    ) 
    or exists (
      select * 
      from `dictionaries` 
        inner join `dictionary_qualification` on `dictionaries`.`id` = `dictionary_qualification`.`dictionary_id` 
      where 
        `qualifications`.`id` = `dictionary_qualification`.`qualification_id` 
        and `type` = ? 
        and `content_pl` = ?
    ) 
    or exists (
      select * 
      from `dictionaries` 
        inner join `dictionary_qualification` on `dictionaries`.`id` = `dictionary_qualification`.`dictionary_id` 
      where 
        `qualifications`.`id` = `dictionary_qualification`.`qualification_id` 
        and `type` = ? 
        and `content_pl` = ?
    ) 
    or exists (
      select * 
      from `dictionaries` 
        inner join `dictionary_qualification` on `dictionaries`.`id` = `dictionary_qualification`.`dictionary_id` 
      where 
        `qualifications`.`id` = `dictionary_qualification`.`qualification_id` 
        and `type` = ? 
        and `content_pl` = ?
    )
)
```

can be reduced to -

```
select * 
from `qualifications` 
where (
    exists (
        select * 
        from `dictionaries` 
        inner join `dictionary_qualification` on `dictionaries`.`id` = `dictionary_qualification`.`dictionary_id` 
        where `qualifications`.`id` = `dictionary_qualification`.`qualification_id` 
        and (
            (`type` = ? and `content_pl` = ?) or
            (`type` = ? and `content_pl` = ?) or
            (`type` = ? and `content_pl` = ?) or
            (`type` = ? and `content_pl` = ?)
        )
        /* or if type is same for all four
        and `type` = ?
        and `content_pl` IN (?, ?, ?, ?)
        */
    ) 
)
```

You can use a similar approach where there is a group of `and exists()` criteria -

```
select * 
from `qualifications` 
where (
    exists (
      select * 
      from `dictionaries` 
        inner join `dictionary_qualification` on `dictionaries`.`id` = `dictionary_qualification`.`dictionary_id` 
      where 
        `qualifications`.`id` = `dictionary_qualification`.`qualification_id` 
        and `type` = ? 
        and `content_pl` = ?
    ) 
    and exists (
      select * 
      from `dictionaries` 
        inner join `dictionary_qualification` on `dictionaries`.`id` = `dictionary_qualification`.`dictionary_id` 
      where 
        `qualifications`.`id` = `dictionary_qualification`.`qualification_id` 
        and `type` = ? 
        and `content_pl` = ?
    ) 
    and exists (
      select * 
      from `dictionaries` 
        inner join `dictionary_qualification` on `dictionaries`.`id` = `dictionary_qualification`.`dictionary_id` 
      where 
        `qualifications`.`id` = `dictionary_qualification`.`qualification_id` 
        and `type` = ? 
        and `content_pl` = ?
    )
)
```

can be reduced to -

```
select * 
from `qualifications` 
where (
    exists (
        select
            `dictionary_qualification`.`qualification_id`,
            count(distinct `content_pl`) num_criteria_matched
        from `dictionaries` 
        inner join `dictionary_qualification` on `dictionaries`.`id` = `dictionary_qualification`.`dictionary_id` 
        where `qualifications`.`id` = `dictionary_qualification`.`qualification_id` 
        and `type` = ?
        and `content_pl` IN (?, ?, ?) # note three values and we want all three to be present
        group by `dictionary_qualification`.`qualification_id`
        having num_criteria_matched = 3 # again, this is the number of values for which we require a match
    ) 
)
```

Comment: You're right. **Exists** queries are mega resource heavy. The only right way to go was to rewrite the auto generation tool to collapse/reduce the queries as you said. Thanks a lot!